# Prometheus - blackbox url is a srv

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, monitoring, victoriametrics

Our Prometheus config file is currently pointing a blackbox-exporter that looks at a website. This is a very basic lookup and would normally not be a issue.

Our issue however is that we use AWS ECS and our containers use bridge mode. This creates a SRV record for the container as part of service discovery. Note: Due to some technical constraints I can't use awsvpc mode, however I know this would solve my problem with a A record.

This is how a normal scrape target would look:

```
- job_name: 'blackbox-google'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - https://www.google.com/
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: blackbox.test.local:9115  # The blackbox exporter's real hostname:port.
```

Our config in Prometheus looks like this:

```
- job_name: 'blackbox-google'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names:
        - blackbox.test.local
        type: SRV
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - https://www.google.com/
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - source_labels: [__meta_dns_srv_record_target, __meta_dns_srv_record_port]
        separator: ":"
        target_label: __address__
```

Now the latter does not work because it would the 2 configs as 2 seperate targets and the __meta tags wouldn't be present in the second target.

Is there anyway to do the lookup and store it in a label and then use the label for another target or job?